# Loop Through json_encoded PHP Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having an issue with looping through an array that was passed from PHP through an Ajax request.

For some reason my javascript thinks that either every character is a part of the array or my response variable is just being passed as a string.

Here is my javascript:

```
<script>        
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/dev/editButton/get_names.php",
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is my PHP:

```
<?php
include '../portfolio/libraries/settings.php';

$connect = mysqli_connect($HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DATABASE);
$query = "SELECT * FROM AUTH_User";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$names = array(); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($names, $row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName']);
}

echo json_encode($names);
?>
```

The response that I get looks like this:

`["Test Person","Test2 Person"]`

**However, if I loop through this using javascript or just print out `response[0]` I get each character as part of the array. The first element would be `[`, next would be `"`, etc.**

**I would like `Test Person` to be one element and `Test2 Person` to be another.**

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use JSON.parse on the response.  Wihtout calling that function you are just getting the index of characters in the JavaScript string.

```
 var resultArray = JSON.parse(response);
 resultArray[0];   //Should Be "test Person"
```

Comment: You can do that, or you can just let jQuery do it for you by setting datatype. Even better, fix the server so it returns `text/json` and jQuery will do it automatically

Comment: Thanks. I actually prefer this method vs. the datatype as I can see what's happening line by line.

Answer (score 2):

The result of the `.ajax` method is interpreted according to the `Content-Type` header of the response. If it is incorrect or not specified, the `response` variable will contain the raw json code as a string.

So one solution is change the PHP code by adding this line:

```
header("Content-Type: text/json");
```

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> The type of pre-processing depends by default upon the Content-Type of
>   the response, but can be set explicitly using the dataType option. If
>   the dataType option is provided, the Content-Type header of the
>   response will be disregarded.

You can parse that text to an object, or you can let JQuery do that for you by specifying a datatype in the call. The `response` parameter will then hold the object instead of the raw json string.

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> If json is specified, the response is parsed using jQuery.parseJSON
>   before being passed, as an object, to the success handler. The parsed
>   JSON object is made available through the responseJSON property of the
>   jqXHR object.

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/dev/editButton/get_names.php",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can also make sure the mime type is set to `text/json`?

Answer (score 1):

In this particular situation, you can use

```
        success: function(response) {
            response = eval(response);
            console.log(response);
        }
```

But this is bad practice.

Really the best solution here is to modify your ajax call as follow:

```
   $(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/dev/editButton/get_names.php",
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

The specified datatype, will request the returned data to be json, and the jquery will automatically parse it to a javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

You must parse JSON to array. You can do this using the following code:

```
var arr = $.parseJSON(response);
```

Now arr[0] should be "Test Person".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the hard way, or this way:

First, you need to specify the return type for AJAX.

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/dev/editButton/get_names.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you could do it this way:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("/dev/editButton/get_names.php", function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

For this to work, you will need to specify the HTML headers accordingly in PHP:

```
<?php
include '../portfolio/libraries/settings.php';

$connect = mysqli_connect($HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DATABASE);
$query = "SELECT * FROM AUTH_User";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$names = array(); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($names, $row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName']);
}

header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($names);
exit();
?>
```

The `exit();` is just for safety so you wouldn't ruin the valid JSON format.

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, so you should not have to do anything complicated there. Here is a simple loop you could use for example:

```
for(var i in response) {
    console.log(response[i]);
}
```

Alternatively, if the response is not an array but an object with properties, you could loop through the object properties by getting the right keys first:

```
var objKeys = Object.keys(response);
for(var i in objKeys) {
    var key = objKeys[i];
    console.log(response[key]);
}
```

I hope this helps!